# Express view render using HBS strips (consumes?) Handlebars client side templates

Tags: node.js, express

Using Express with Don Park's HBS as the view engine, with the intention of using the same templating style for both client and server code. However I have run into a bit of a snag.

With the index.hbs shown here,

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>Welcome to {{title}}</p>

<div id="place"></div>

<script id="firstTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <ul>
    {{#lines}}
      <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/lines}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

Heres what renders to the browser:

```
<h1>Express</h1>
<p>Welcome to Express</p>

<div id="place"></div>

<script id="firstTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <ul>

  </ul>
</script>
```

The Express View render process seems to have consumed the template block intended for use in the browser. As far as I can tell, the view renderer just takes the entire file.hbs as a string tempate to render, not distinguishing the script block from server view.

Any ideas/workarounds for this?

Comment: You could try changing the delimiter right before the script tag `{{=<% %>=}}`

Comment: Yes, I was looking for how to do this! Couldnt find it with Handlebars so I modified a copy of ICanHaz to do the client templating with altered delimiters.  

Can you share a code sample to show how to put this delimiter change into the file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Handlebars in the same way and ran into the same problem.

I worked around it by storing this part:

```
<script id="firstTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <ul>
    {{#lines}}
      <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/lines}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

In a separate static file and then loading it via ajax after the page has rendered. This way my client-side template doesn't get mistakenly rendered by Express.

It would be nice though if there were a way to add a tag to let Express know to ignore blocks like that and leave them for the client-side.

Answer (score 1):

If handlebars is truly compatible with Mustache, then this should work:

Change your delimiter first by putting this somewhere at the top of your template ( before any template placeholders )

```
{{=<% %>=}}
```

So now anything you want rendered by the server you will do:

```
<% foo %>
```

And anything you want rendered on the client like so:

```
{{ bar }}
```

More info is at the bottom of the Mustache manual here - http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html

Comment: Not sure this answers the question as OP doesnt mention mustache anywhere.. also this solution throws an error for a pure handlebars solution

Answer (score 0):

For handlebars, uou can use backslash to escape the double braces, like so:

```
<script id="firstTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <ul>
    \{{#lines}}
      <li>\{{name}}</li>
    \{{/lines}}
  </ul>
</script>
```